# gif buttons won't center to top

Tags: html, css

```css
/* button gifs */
.button-gifs {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 5px;
  align:center;
  min-width: 120px;
}

/* Ion Cannon */
.earth{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ubEXxDA.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.earth:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/MDbvuYW.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* dachshund head */
.dachshund-head{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/XDPDMXu.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.dachshund-head:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/GICiErd.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* ChickenWifRabies */
.ChickenWifRabies{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/wqBqdjb.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.ChickenWifRabies:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/8H4lx1u.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Gateways */
.Gateways{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/kunVntT.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.Gateways:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/7gth567.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Games */
.Games{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/0gwiz6c.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.Games:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/3w29EWf.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Pride */
.Pride{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ZVQmYAu.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.Pride:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ErHvozs.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Learning */
.Learning{
    width: 120px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/1yn3nlz.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.Learning:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/LAKluIV.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- Ion Canon -->
<div class="earth button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#space'" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>

<!-- Dachshund Head -->
<div class="dachshund-head button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#dog'" style="cursor: pointer;"> </div>

<!-- ChickenWifRabies -->
<div class="ChickenWifRabies button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#chickens'" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>

<!-- Gateways -->
<div class="Gateways button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#metal'" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
  
  <!-- Games -->
  <div class="Games button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#gaming'" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
  
    <!-- Pride -->
  <div class="Pride button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#pride'" style="cursor: pointer;" ></div>
  
      <!-- Learning -->
  <div class="Learning button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#learning'" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
  
    <!-- Bananaman Gif -->
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yModCU1OVHY">
    
  <img id="gif-2" class="button-gifs" src="https://i.imgur.com/QpylKJJ.png" 
    onmouseover="document.getElementById('gif-2').src='https://i.imgur.com/F5eUUiV.gif'" 
     onmouseout="document.getElementById('gif-2').src='https://i.imgur.com/QpylKJJ.png'" </img></a>
```

So.. I'm tired and I tried a lot of different things, floating, transpose, etc and can't seem to find a way to get these buttons to **sit still at the top of the page and centered**. Bananaman was my first gif made into a button, I could just make it the same way as the others but I'm already swamped. The video background I used for this site was giving me issues but I fixed it.
I just would like to know what I could do in order for this to work.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve if possible with some visual representation?

Comment: Provide a clear insight on what is the outcome you are expecting.

Comment: Could you put up a minimal example snippet - perhaps with just one button so we can see the problem clearly.

Comment: My bad, I added a snippet of it, didn't know that's how that work lmfao. I'm tired and sorry. I'm just trying to get them to be side by side and centered at the top of page without them moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to horizontally center the content, you can add a simple content wrapper div like this:

```css
.content {
    position: absolute;
    /* center the element */
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    /* give it dimensions */
    width: 80%;
}


/* button gifs */
.button-gifs {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 5px;
  align:center;
  min-width: 120px;
}

/* Ion Cannon */
.earth{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ubEXxDA.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.earth:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/MDbvuYW.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* dachshund head */
.dachshund-head{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/XDPDMXu.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.dachshund-head:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/GICiErd.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* ChickenWifRabies */
.ChickenWifRabies{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/wqBqdjb.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.ChickenWifRabies:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/8H4lx1u.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Gateways */
.Gateways{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/kunVntT.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.Gateways:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/7gth567.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Games */
.Games{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/0gwiz6c.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.Games:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/3w29EWf.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Pride */
.Pride{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ZVQmYAu.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.Pride:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ErHvozs.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Learning */
.Learning{
    width: 120px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/1yn3nlz.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.Learning:hover{
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/LAKluIV.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<!-- Ion Canon -->
<div class="earth button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#space'" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>

<!-- Dachshund Head -->
<div class="dachshund-head button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#dog'" style="cursor: pointer;"> </div>

<!-- ChickenWifRabies -->
<div class="ChickenWifRabies button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#chickens'" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>

<!-- Gateways -->
<div class="Gateways button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#metal'" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
  
  <!-- Games -->
  <div class="Games button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#gaming'" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
  
    <!-- Pride -->
  <div class="Pride button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#pride'" style="cursor: pointer;" ></div>
  
      <!-- Learning -->
  <div class="Learning button-gifs" onclick="window.location.href='#learning'" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
  
    <!-- Bananaman Gif -->
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yModCU1OVHY">
    
  <img id="gif-2" class="button-gifs" src="https://i.imgur.com/QpylKJJ.png" 
    onmouseover="document.getElementById('gif-2').src='https://i.imgur.com/F5eUUiV.gif'" 
     onmouseout="document.getElementById('gif-2').src='https://i.imgur.com/QpylKJJ.png'" </img></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This was extremely close and I think I can take it from here. Fixed would make it float over all the text on the site but this is close enough that I can work with.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know there was other content. I've updated it to position: absolute; No worries, glad to help :) It would be good if you could choose as accepted answer/upvote so I get some rep points ;D cheers

Answer (score 1):

Change `align: center`  to `vertical-align: top`

```
.button-gifs {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 10%;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work at all but thank you very much for trying.